# How to delete text scrolling by X in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add something like position sticky to my text in labels in the chart.
In first image you can see how I want to position text in my chart.

Maybe someone know to fix my problem. My code is in the bottom. Thanks!
I want to disable moving text under the line

```
    Highcharts.chart(container, {
      chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
          minWidth: window.innerWidth < 767 ? 767 : null,
          scrollPositionX: 0,
          marginTop: 20
        },
        events: {
          render() {
            let chart = this,
              legend = chart.legend,
              firstElem = legend.scrollGroup.element.firstElementChild,
              secondElem = legend.scrollGroup.element.lastElementChild;

            // set legend name positions - they are relative to the path, so value can be fixed
            firstElem.children[1].setAttribute('x', 40);
            firstElem.children[1].setAttribute('y', 10);

            secondElem.children[1].setAttribute('x', 20);
            secondElem.children[1].setAttribute('y', 10);

            // after resize - if bottom text exist - destroy it 
            if (chart.text1) {
              chart.text1.destroy()
            }

            if (chart.text2) {
              chart.text2.destroy();
            }
            // render bottom text
            chart.text1 = chart.renderer.text(minX + " - " + maxX + " грн", legend.group.translateX + chart.plotLeft, legend.group.translateY + 40).add();
            chart.text2 = chart.renderer.text(minXY + " - " + maxXY + " °C", legend.group.translateX(50%) + chart.plotLeft + legend.group.getBBox().width / 2, legend.group.translateY + 40).add();
          }


        },
        spacingBottom: 100
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: null
      },
      xAxis: [{
        endOnTick: true,
        startOnTick: true,
        gridLineColor: "#EDEDED",
        min: 0,
                overflow: "allow",
        labels: {
                    overflow: "allow",
          format: "{value}",
          style: {
            color: "#8F969A",
            fontSize: 11,
            fontFamily: "Roboto"
          }
        },


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily disable this moving by adding those texts into to **legend.group** which is fixed.

```
chart.text1 = chart.renderer.text(minX + " - " + maxX + " грн", 20, 40).add(legend.group);
chart.text2 = chart.renderer.text(minXY + " - " + maxXY + " °C", 200, 40).add(legend.group);
```

Same like above - they are relative to the legend.group, so value can be fixed

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywfgLphv/1/

Comment: maybe you also know how to add bold style to this text?)

Comment: Yep - it could be done in the css property - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jhf2wyqv/

Comment: Oh, I am delighted with your knowledge of this library, I sat for 4 hours thinking how to do it. BIG thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) Highcharts support team is always willing to help!

Comment: I'm so sorry it's will be my last question  if you will agree. how to add border-radius 6px to that yellow and blue lines? Thanks

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible without doing some deep core changes, because this line is rendered as a path line.